# Fantasy TV series set on a pacific island?

Tags: story-identification

I am looking for a surfer/fantasy TV series targeted towards I think all ages where I watched it maybe three or four years ago. I think the main target audience were children and it sounds a bit like this....

- Centered around pacifica culture/mythology
- Set somewhere on a island in the pacific (perhaps Tonga, Samoa)
- Features/includes ghosts (Some are European ghosts dressed in clothing similar to that of Captain Cook)
- Possibly had elements of mystery which was part of the plot
- There is some type of evil called Ragnerauff (I think) who looks green or dark green and is the main villain in the series. He wears some type of coral looking cloak/thing and reminds me of a dementor from Harry Potter
- I remember that he was imprisoned in a coral reef prison by a surfer with magical powers who has some type of necklace
- The TV series name had the word cafe in it (I think) and on this island there was a cafe
- It is not a cartoon/animation
- Surfing is a main thing on the island
- The surfer was re-incarnated again but no one knew who it was. There was this white guy and this other guy with an afro and they though it was the white guy who was this surfer
- The evil villain sends this girl to find out who the new surfer is so that he can be used to set the villain free from his prison

I think some details might be incorrect as I have not watched this in years. Does anyone know if they can match this up to a series you might know?

Comment: This reminds me a little of [Lightning Point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightning_Point) AKA [_Alien Surf Girls_](http://aliensurfgirls.wikia.com/wiki/Alien_Surf_Girls) but not quite and Lightning Point was only one season long =\

Comment: @22ndCenturyFza the OP doesn't say there should be more than 1 season.

Comment: I'm actually not sure how many seasons there are but it isn't Lightning Point. I have watched that before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're describing "[Paradise Café](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paradise_Caf%C3%A9)"

The show was set on a Paradise Island, in the south pacific. The villain was called "Ragnar" and he was imprisoned in a 'Coral prison' until he was released by the main character's necklace.

The show extensively features ghosts, monsters, elements of mystery, etc.

Comment: Keep an eye out for the token black character on this otherwise totally white "pacific island"...

Comment: This is it thanks. :)